# Get posts with the same tag by clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have the next code:

```js
$('.left article').on('click', function(event) {
   var article_content = $(this).children('.article-content').html()
 $('.right').html(article_content);
});
```

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display: flex;
}

section > div {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}

.left .article-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="left">
     <article>
        <h2>My post title</h2>
        <div class="article-content"><p>This is the content for the first article</p></div>
        </article>

     <article>
        <h2>Another post title</h2>
        <div class="article-content"><p>Content for the the second post</p></div>
        </article>

     <article>
        <h2>Third post title</h2>
        <div class="article-content"><p>This is the content for the third post</p></div>
        </article>
  </div>


  <div class="right">

  </div>
</section>
```

The same principle i want to implement in my wordpress code, for displaying the titles of the posts and the content of them, plus i want to add a new column with a list of posts from diferent custom post type(ex: testpostype), what will have the same 'tag', what was added by the user.

For example: i have the list of posts from BOOK post type, every post has different tag, 1 -tag1, 2-tag 2, 3 -tag 3. In the same time i have other customp post type (testpostype), where i have also posts with the same tags as in my BOOK post type.  I want, when i will click on first post from BOOK post type, to get the content  of the post, plus the list of posts from second post type (testpostype), what will contain the same tag. EX: i click on first post (with tag1)+i get the content+ i get the post from second post type with tag1.

I have the next code, but i have to modify it for getting the same result. Who knows how?

```js
<section>
        <div class="left">
           <?php global $post;
                 $wpposts = get_posts('numberposts=3&post_type=>book');
                  foreach($wpposts as $post):
                     setup_postdata($post);
           ?>
            <article>
                <h2>
                    <ul>
                       <li>
                          <?php the_title(); ?>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </h2>
                <div class="article-content">
                    <p>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </article>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: @designtocode, how should the code looks?

Comment: you are going to have to get the tags in the left loop and pass the tags in ajax to request a new wp_query and load it in the third column. This is a bit of coding, so I'd suggest trying to create this first and post on StackOverflow if you're having any issues.